# Spring boot neo4j @NodeEntity with Integer property throwing error

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When I use data type as Integer/int for field rowStatusId, I am able to save node to neo4j database using .save() method but while retrieving the record using findByName(String name), system throwing error as below (error occurred at "LineItemStatus status = lineItemStatusRepository.findByName("New");" in service ). I am not receiving any error when I change the data type to Long.

Can't we use Integer? or do I need to include any other dependencies? Please help me.

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel

Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [int]
```

Below is my code

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity
public class LineItemStatus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int rowStatusId;

    public LineItemStatus(String name, String description, int rowStatusId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.rowStatusId = rowStatusId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getRowStatusId() {
        return rowStatusId;
    }

    public void setRowStatusId(int rowStatusId) {
        this.rowStatusId = rowStatusId;
    }
}
```

reopsioty:

```
import com.ns.tbe.model.nodes.LineItemStatus;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface LineItemStatusRepository extends Neo4jRepository<LineItemStatus, Long> {
    LineItemStatus findByName(String name);
}
```

Service:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class LineItemStatusService {
    @Autowired
    LineItemStatusRepository lineItemStatusRepository;

    public void saveLineItemStatus() {
        lineItemStatusRepository.save(new LineItemStatus("New", "new", 1));
        lineItemStatusRepository.save(new LineItemStatus("Modified", "modified", 1));
        lineItemStatusRepository.save(new LineItemStatus("Deleted", "deleted", 1));

        LineItemStatus status = lineItemStatusRepository.findByName("New");
    }
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.ns'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
    compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver', version: '3.2.11'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.10'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=secret
```

Answer (score 1):

Drivers tend to store integers as longs. Here is a nicely detailed explanation of what is going on: https://michael-simons.github.io/neo4j-sdn-ogm-tips/understand_the_type_system.html.

To simplify things, you may want to change `rowStatusId` to be of type `long`.

Comment: I am able to resolve my errors with Long data type. But, even with int I can able to perform all the operations in SDN-Rx reactive spring boot. Why the same functionality is not available in non reactive neo4j spring boot JPA.